# How to Deploy web application in jetty externally?

Tags: eclipse, maven, jetty, datasource, jndi

I have a web application that works fine with tomcat inside eclipse . So now i am trying  to deploy it in jetty.

Things done:
a) installed and check the jetty server from command line(works fine).

TODO:

a) how and where to deploy the application in jetty ?

b) how to define the datasource jndi settings in jetty(i tried in jetty)
.xml but it throws error regarding classesNOTFOund...

Comment: Are you trying to use an maven embedded Jetty or really an external jetty server ?

Comment: externally.  then trying to deploy war in /webapp

Comment: So, like any other Servlet Container, you can look here to jnow "How to deploy" : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951354/how-to-deploy-web-application-in-jetty-externally. About datasource, within eclipse you have to configure it a simple file : WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml. It's probably the same for external server.